# Replacing Windows XP completely to Ubuntu (booting issues)

Tags: usb, dvd, windows-xp, bios

I am trying  to replace my old existing Windows XP(service pack 3) completely with Ubuntu latest desktop version over the last two days with no sucess due to the following:

1. Created both a bootable USB, and DVD loaded both with new boot
   files, despite many attempted changing bios settings and boot
   sequences. Computer refuses to boot from these devices.
2. All files are present and correct in both the created DVD & bootable
   usb formats but all I get is continued black sceen stating:

   `Remove disks or other media - Press any key to restart.`

I have to remove USB stick, otherwise press any key results in repeated request.

I then hear DVD spinning followed by:

```
No boot device available - strike F1 to retry boot, F2 for setup utility
```

Assistance would be most appreciated!

Comment: Can you give us a model number for your system? This can help us help you.

Comment: Are you sure the USB and DVD are bootable? How did you create them?

Answer (score 0):

On windows I will suggest you to use [universal-usb-installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create a bootable USB with Ubuntu .

Once you have created bootable usb with it, boot with it.

Select you USB stick in boot option upon start-up  by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>(key may be different).
Alternatively you can change your boot order from BIOS setup.